# How to save our "desktop state"?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, desktop

Every time I change my screen resolution, my "arranged desktop" goes unarranged.

And even when I change back the screen resolution, it does not get "rearranged".

I was wondering: Are there any solutions to this problem?

(32 Bit Windows Vista Home Premium SP2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of two utility programs for this. PC Magazine's WinTidy and Iconoid. PC Mag charges for downloads. Iconoid is available free from http://www.sillysot.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have my parents set up with [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/), a program that allows you to group and organize your desktop icons. Also, the animation for shifting icons around on screen when you drag one through a group of other icons is *amazing*.

It's free.

Comment: Just checked today - free for 30 days - then it costs...

Answer (score 1):

Probably overpowering, but I use Dextop.  It's a virtual desktop manager. It also has a nice feature that directs new windows to which ever desktop you placed a program on the last run.

The drawback is the programs are constantly running.