# How to stop Windows 10 rearranging desktop icons with screen resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, icons

I have an ASUS K501U windows laptop 4k display, which I have turned down to 1080P so I can record the screen without crashing during classes.  Whenever I plug in a projector and duplicate the screen, the screen stays with the current resolution.  If extending the screen to a low resolution projector, it decides to go to 4k for no apparent reason.

A weird side effect is that I have arranged my icons in the top left of the screen so they would fit regardless of resolution, either 1080p or 4k.  Yet every time the screen resolution changes, Windows destroys my arrangement.

The following article has no useful suggestions.  The auto rearrange option is OFF on my computer.
http://www.winability.com/how-to-i-stop-windows-from-rearranging-my-desktop-icons/

Does anyone know why Windows would rearrange icons when not asked to do so, or how to stop this from happening?
Alternatively, if there is any way to stop the screen from erroneously going to 4k when I plug in an external monitor that would be good too.

Comment: First, windows is trying to be helpful by making sure the icons are all within the view area.  Yes, I get it, you would like an option to turn it off. Not finding that I've resolved to use Desktop Save & Restore.  There are several out there, my personal favorite: http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/desktoprestore.htm ... it won't stop the icons from re-arranging but it will help you get them back to where they belong, so long as you have a saved config (save before you attach anything, attach the thing, restore, rearrange, save with new descriptive name. lather rinse repeat

Comment: I've seen this question asked a few times here. You can find answers (including mine) at:  http://superuser.com/questions/306704/how-to-save-our-desktop-state/306708#306708 and    http://superuser.com/questions/290078/how-do-i-stop-windows-from-moving-desktop-icons/1129243#1129243

Comment: @TG2: All the icons are within viewing location under both resolutions.  Windows is being an ass.

Comment: @Dov lol... I'd agree .. and what about the open applications, even if they are minimized ... windows resolution changes screws with those too... wish those things could be saved too :)

Comment: I have a docking station, and my icons get re-arranged every time I dock/undock on W10. All three displays are the same resolution. I never had this issue on W7, and the laptop display was lower resolution than monitors. Third party software is not an option due to this being a work PC. Would love a real solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this on other post here (this site) and it's worked for me!

Run regedit... in RUN > regedit ... and go to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies

Create (if not always exists) a Key called Explorer

add new DWORD value called NoSaveSettings and set it to 0

Restart your computer and all is fixed!

Comment: Add the link to the other post.

Comment: "NoSaveSettings." Do you have any documentation on which settings are affected?

Comment: "and all is fixed" All is not fixed. The icons are still in scrambled places. You must mean something else.

Comment: I think Windows must save separate icon locations for each possible scaling. I don't know if this is also true for resolution.

Answer (score -1):

What I found was if the primary display was using the older connection (VGA compared to DVI) than the seconday, the icons would move.  Once I used the newest connection for my primary monitor, all was good.  Before that, I was putting a single icon on the secondary desktop to keep them from moving.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when I would switch between an external monitor and just using my laptop. Try going to Display Settings, Scale and Layout. Under "Change the size text, apps and other items", ensure it is set to 100%. HTH.

Comment: When resolution changes, even if scaling is set to 100%, the icons will move.